# NGINX CORS ISSUE

Tags: ajax, nginx, iframe

Is there a way around to avoid **CORS** issue using nginx. My one application is running no netty-server which comes with play framework using joc.lan as domain name and other application is on php web server which i had integrated in my application which uses **iframe** to load and it uses **chat.joc.lan** as domain name which is a subdomain of **joc.lan**.

So,when anyone of my application tries to access any data for other application,the error i get on console is

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://chat.joc.lan" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://joc.lan". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

I had resolved this error by setting **document.domain** on both application as the main domain name which is joc.lan.
And for ajax requests i am using **JSONP**.

I had read somewhere it's not supported on firefox and IE.

The first once is for my main application joc.lan

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  joc.lan;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # WebSocket support (nginx 1.4)
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        }
}
```

the second one i am interating inside joc.lan using iframe.

```
server {
                listen  80;
                server_name chat.joc.lan;
                root /opt/apps/flyhi/chat;
                index   index.php;
                # caching for images and disable access log for images
                location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml|ttf|eot)$ {
                        access_log              off;
                        expires                 360d;
                }


                 # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9007

location ~ \.php {
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9011;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    access_log off;
}


location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?r=$request_uri;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but you can set the parameters in nginx config file for allowing CORS in all browsers.
[This link can be a help where there is nginx config file is given to allow CORS](https://gist.github.com/michiel/1064640)

Comment: yeah,that might work for ajax calls,which i am taking care from server. It will not work if my sub-domain which  is chat.joc.lan when it is trying to access any data from parent domain which is joc.lan